# Turning a multi-dimensional array into a hash without overwriting values

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, hash

I have a multi-dimensional array such as:

```
array = [["stop", "halt"],["stop", "red"],["go", "green"],["go","fast"],["caution","yellow"]]
```

And I want to turn it into a hash like this:

```
hash = {"stop" => ["halt","red"], "go" => ["green","fast"], "caution" => "yellow"}
```

However, when I array.to_h , the values overwrite one another and I get:

```
hash = {"stop" => "red", "go" => "fast", "caution" => "yellow"}
```

How do I get the desired array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way. It uses [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) and the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
array << ["stop", "or I'll fire!"]

array.each_with_object({}) { |(f,l),h|
  h.update(f=>l) { |_,ov,nv| ov.is_a?(Array) ? ov << nv : [ov, nv] } }
  #=> {"stop"=>["halt", "red", "or I'll fire!"],
  #    "go"=>["green", "fast"],
  #    "caution"=>"yellow"}
```

The code is simplified if you want all values in the returned hash to be arrays (i.e., `"caution"=>["yellow"]`), which is generally more convenient for subsequent calculations:

```
array.each_with_object({}) { |(f,l),h|  h.update(f=>[l]) {|_,ov,nv| ov+nv }}
  #=> {"stop"=>["halt", "red", "or I'll fire!"],
  #    "go"=>["green", "fast"],
  #    "caution"=>["yellow"]}
```

Comment: Thank you, Cary!  I'm only a few weeks into coding (in any language), so I'm still trying to get familiar with many methods and abbreviations.  I've been searching articles for good explanations of each_with_object and can't find anything that really makes negotiating it clear to me.  Do you know where I can find a good explanation?  Also, is there an efficient way to do the above but keep all the values as arrays?

Comment: Garrett, there's nothing mysterious about `Enumerable#each_with_object`, which made its debut in v. 1.9. Suppose `a` is an array and you wish to do this: `b = []; a.each { |e| b << e+1;  b`; that is, 1. create an object (`b=[]`); 2. do something with each element of `a`; and 3. return the object (`b`). This is a very common pattern. `a.each_with_object([]) { |e,b| b << e+1 }` allows you to do that in one line rather than three. Nothing more, nothing less. Think of the method as, "`each`, with an object". I'll edit to address your  other question.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the additional code above!  It adds a lot of clarification.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
array.inject({}) {|r, (k, v)| r[k] &&= [*r[k], v]; r[k] ||= v; r }
```

That's pretty messy though. Written out, it looks like this:

```
def to_hash_with_duplicates(arr)
  {}.tap do |r|
    arr.each do |k, v|
      r[k] &&= [*r[k], v]    # key already present, turn into array and add value
      r[k] ||= v             # key not present, simply store value
    end
  end
end
```

Edit: Thinking a bit more, `@cary-swoveland`'s update-with-block solution is better, because it handles `nil` and `false` values correctly.